# PHP 5.6 configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-spl, --with-ttf

Tags: php

I'm trying to install PHP 5.6.13 on Cent OS 7, but i'm getting this error:

```
PHP 5.6 configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-spl, --with-ttf
```

Can someone tell me how to fix it?

this is my configuration:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/ --datadir=/usr/share/php5/ 
--mandir=/usr/share/man --bindir=/usr/bin --includedir=/usr/include 
--sysconfdir=/etc/php5/apache2 --with-config-file-path=/etc/php5/apache2 
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php5/conf.d --enable-libxml 
--enable-session --with-mm --with-pcre-regex --enable-xml 
--enable-simplexml --enable-spl --enable-filter --disable-debug 
--enable-inline-optimization --disable-rpath --disable-static 
--enable-shared --program-suffix=5 --with-pic --with-apxs2 
--disable-all --enable-cli --enable-dom --enable-mbstring --with-zlib 
--with-libdir=lib64 --with-gd --with-sybase-ct=/usr/local/freetds/ 
--enable-gd-native-ttf --with-ttf --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-iconv 
--enable-ctype --with-openssl --enable-zip --enable-xmlwriter 
--with-ldap –with-openssl
```

Comment: It says that those options don't exist... Why do you think they should?

Comment: TTF was removed after version 5.3.0. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=658248

Comment: @aynber Thanks for your reply, i'll remove it from the configuration

Comment: Why don't you use package manager to install PHP in first place? (yum install php)

Comment: @rkosegi in my work i have to build php from the source without package manager. to configure it with custom options and dependancies. :)